# AOT Reflection not working as expected?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I'm writing some code to search the AOT for certain objects and just doing an Extended Data Type search isn't working as expected.  I created, in the USR layer, an EDT called "Alex" with an EnumType of "SysDimension".  It can't find it in the AOT, but it can find others.

```
static void Job6(Args _args)
{
    #AOT
    TreeNodeIterator    treeNodeIterator;
    TreeNode            treeNode;
    SysDictEnum         sysDictEnum;
    ;

    treeNodeIterator    = TreeNode::findNode(#ExtendedDataTypesPath).AOTiterator();
    treeNode            = treeNodeIterator.next();
    while (treeNode)
    {
        sysDictEnum         = new SysDictEnum(treeNode.applObjectId());

        if (sysDictEnum)
        {
            if (sysDictEnum.name() == "Alex")
                info("Found Alex"); // WHY ISN'T THIS FOUND?

            if (sysDictEnum.name() == "ABCModel")
                info("Found ABCModel"); // THIS IS OUTPUT
        }

        treeNode = treeNodeIterator.next();
    }

    info("Done");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I feel stupid.  I was iterating over the Extended Data Types but using sysDictEnum instead of sysDictType,  which is for EDTs.  Explains my confusing results.

Comment: It can happen to the best of us... and I think it just did! ;D

Comment: I like how it makes me wait 2 days before accepting an answer so I have to wallow in the shame...

Comment: Hahahaha.... This sorts of chats have nothing to do with stackoverflow, but I can't restrain myself. Thanks for sharing both question, solution and a good laugh!